# Checking if a board configuration is valid (similar to Sudoku )

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, iteration

I have a puzzle that involves a board that will look like this:

The outside numbers represent how many visible "buildings" can be seen from facing in that direction. SO if there is a 1 on the north side of column 1, then that column would have to be a 6, since you could only see one building. Reminder: the board hasn't been completely populated yet.

```
   1 4 2 2 2 3 
   -----------
 1|. . . 2 . .|4
 3|3 4 . . . .|2
 3|. . . 1 . .|2
 2|. 1 . . . .|4
 6|. . . . . 6|1
 2|5 . 1 . . 4|2
   ----------- 
   2 1 3 4 3 2
```

I'm having difficulties implementing an `isValid` method that will check if the current configuration of the board is valid.

A correct configuration example would look like:

```
   1 2 3 3 
   --------
 1|4 3 2 1 |4
 2|1 4 3 2 |3
 2|3 2 1 4 |1
 2|2 1 4 3 |2
   --------     
   3 3 1 2
```

My `isValid` method:

```
/**
 * You must do some sort of pruning (removing excessive possibilities) in your isValid method
 * @return boolean
 */
@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    //check for duplicates first
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int r = 0; r < this.dimension; r++) { //Row
        for (int c = 0; c < this.dimension; c++) { //Column
            set.add(this.board[r][c]);//Add all the values from a array into a set
        }
        if(set.size()< this.board.length) {//If the size of the set is less than the array length
            return false;//The config is invalid
        }
        set.clear();//If not invalid, move onto the next array and clear the set.
    }

    //Now I need to check when the board becomes fully populated(no empty positions remaining)
    //check all the looking values for any violations(NS, SN, EW, WE)
    //... Not sure how to do this

    return true;
}
```

I have come to the conclusion that I need to check for duplicates in rows/columns, and also when the board becomes fully populated (no empty positions remaining), check all the looking values for any violations.

My board's data structure is a 2D array(`public int[][] board;`)

And I represented the outside numbers as 4 separate arrays:

`public int[] NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;`

I don't know how to check if my board configuration is valid.
I've been struggling with this for some hours now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am with a doubt about the question. Would you like to check at "playing time" if each user suggestion is correct? by the way, what is the name of this game?

Comment: so the puzzle is called Skyscrapers. isValid is A boolean method that takes a SkyscraperConfig and returns whether or not it is valid. You must do some sort of pruning (removing excessive possibilities) in your isValid method